# Google Sheet Cell to execute Google search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with a list of companies (Column A) and I'd like to know if both options below can be executed by way of a function within google sheets:

1) Find domain name and put it in Column B

2) Run a 'site:domain.com [search term]' google search and return '1' if successful or '0' if no results.

Edit: Sample Google Sheet.

[image]

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a sample image of your sheet

Comment: Added a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: Take a look at [Url FetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bound Apps script to your sheet. And make a custom function that you can use as a formula in your sheet.

Using the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` function you can get the results from any website by making a request to its URL such as **https://www.google.com**.

Keep in mind, the function will return HTML code, that you will have to parse to extract the string you want from the HTML content returned. for this you can use more regex.

```js
function searchResults(input) {
  var url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+the+website+of+company+"+encodeURIComponent(input);
  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  var searchResults = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var titleExp = /<h2 class=\"result__title\">([\s\S]*?)<\/h2>/gi;
  var titleResults = searchResults.getContentText().match(titleExp);
  // return the first match
  return titleResults[0];
}
```

---

**Recommended reading:**

- [Custom functions in google shests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#getting_started)
- [Extending Google sheets with Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: What's the best way to parse HTML within a cell? Just to get the URL (i.e. aa.com)

Comment: Every website will have a different HTML code and style of presenting the results. What you normally have to do is inspect the website code, and notice which HTML tag(s) is where the title of the results is coming from, so that you can tailor a regex expression to your precise need

Comment: +Aerials - I got this to work. How can I decode the URL encoding (i.e. %2F) in the titleResutls?

Comment: @BigMike good to hear that. You can use the Javascript standard built-in function [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to decode it.